# WMS response renders badly for the first seconds

Tags: geoserver, openlayers

I am using geoserver and oL3 to load a WMS layer. The layer is created with visibility:false and when I zoom in the map, I turn it on. While everything works fine I have noticed that for a second I get an ugly, nasty, displayed image of the layer before it renders completely.

Look at the screenshot[image] Its ugly. Any idea what could be the issue? I have tried in different OS and with different browsers. Same issue always.

Comment: Is the data used to create the WMS quite simple, is it stored in a database?

Comment: Yes. The data are very simple polygons (4 vertices) stored in a postgis database. Using a geoserver store to get them.

Comment: If I recall correctly I think there is option on the geoserver postgis configuration about providing simplified geometry that you should untick.

Comment: I should untick it? Wouldn't be that having simplified geometry makes things faster? In any case this option "Support on the fly geometry simplification" is unticked in my geoserver store! Another thing is that the geoserver layer is actually a view. Could this cause the issue?

Comment: What you see as a blob is, I think, a simplified version of your data.  Your data is already simple, where's the need to simplify it.

Comment: I see your point. But this option is unticked. I have some other options though such as "Loose box" and "Estimated extends". I can unticking them although I dont think they are related.